# NSTextView is really slow when background is transparent

Tags: xcode, macos, performance, background, nstextview

I'm making a Mac OSX application and I need to use a `NSTextView` with transparent background (unchecking the option "Draws Background"), but the problem is that when I write a lot of text with a lot of lines (eg: 20000 lines), the textview becomes really slow. In fact, all the app becomes very slow, not only the textview.

That doesn't happen if background is opaque.

Any ideas about how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicated issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35728127/transparent-nstextview-performance

Comment: I tried enabling `allowsNonContiguousLayout` but it doesn't work.